# Issues with binding xaml with json serialization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have issues showing data in my xamarin forms .xaml with REST API using json serialization.

Console.WriteLine("test products: " + ProductList.Count); does return the productlist (55) but it doesnt view.

I also have this error

[0:] Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[xxx_xxxxx.Models.Category]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'message', line 1, position 11.: \tERROR {0}

I can't figure out what the problem is.

**RESTAPIService.cs**

```
public RestAPIService()
{
   client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.xxxxxxx.xx/xx/") };

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<Products>> GetProducts()
{
   products = new ObservableCollection<Products>();

   var token = SecureStorage.GetAsync("AuthKey");

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("www-authentication", await token);
            
    try
    {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("products");
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
          var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Products>>(content);
          Console.WriteLine("response products: " + products.Count);

           }
      }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            return products;
        }
```

**Products.cs** My Modal Class

```
    public class ImageFront
    {
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string contents { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object thumb { get; set; }
        public int? width { get; set; }
        public int? height { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImageThumb
    {
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string contents { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object thumb { get; set; }
        public int? width { get; set; }
        public int? height { get; set; }
    }

    public class File
    {
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string contents { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string indication { get; set; }
        public string weight { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string usage_days { get; set; }
        public string usage_dosage { get; set; }
        public string usage_how { get; set; }
        public string dosage { get; set; }
        public string allergie { get; set; }
        public string nutrition { get; set; }
        public string preserve { get; set; }
        public string shelf_distribution { get; set; }
        public string shelf_prod_nr { get; set; }
        public string shelf_life { get; set; }
        public string charge { get; set; }
        public string shelf_description { get; set; }
        public string webtext { get; set; }
        public string daily_dosage { get; set; }
        public object ingredients { get; set; }
        public object composition { get; set; }
        public string factor { get; set; }
        public string risk_analysis { get; set; }
        public string conclusion { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string purchase_price { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double sales_price { get; set; }
        public string tax_rate { get; set; }
        public string min_stock { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string fabrikant_id { get; set; }
        public bool archive { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string price_original { get; set; }
        public string sales_price_original { get; set; }
        public int current_stock { get; set; }
        public bool stock_warning { get; set; }
        public ImageFront image_front { get; set; }
        public ImageThumb image_thumb { get; set; }
        public List<File> File { get; set; }
    }

    public class Products
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Products> products;

        public ProductViewModel()
        {
            ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
            GetProducts();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Products> ProductList
        {
            get { return products; }
            set
            {
                products = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public async void GetProducts()
        {
            ProductList.Clear();
            ProductList = await App.RestAPIManager.GetProductsAsync();
            
            Console.WriteLine("test products: " + ProductList.Count);

        }
}
```

**ProductPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xxx_xxxxx.Views.ProductPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:xxx_xxxxx.ViewModels" xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xxx_xxxxxx.xxxxxx">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ProductViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>        
        <CollectionView x:Name="productList"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                SelectionMode="Single"
                         BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Product.name}" 
                            FontSize="Small"
                             TextColor="Blue"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Product.price}" 
                            FontSize="Small" />
                        <Button Text="hoi">
                            
                        </Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: your biding expression should just be `Text="{Binding name}"`, etc

Comment: Member not found in data context ''Products' error

Comment: I defined ProductList in the ProductViewModel.cs as public ObservableCollection<Products> ProductList{}. The point was to iterate the products and show them in the collectionview

Comment: Yes it is a C# property

Comment: is the "hoi" button displaying?

Comment: Yeah I was testing if the hoi button was displaying but no succes :(

Comment: So, "No, the HOI button is not visible"?

Comment: The hoi button is not visible indeed

Comment: That means there is a problem with your ItemsSource that you need to solve first.  Try setting it manually in `GetProducts` instead of using a binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the prefix of the `Product` when binding.

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="productList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
            SelectionMode="Single"
                     BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                        FontSize="Small"
                         TextColor="Blue"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding price}" 
                        FontSize="Small" />
                    <Button Text="hoi">
                        
                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Note:We should code like this:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                        FontSize="Small"
                         TextColor="Blue"/>
```

instead of the following code:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Product.name}" 
                        FontSize="Small"
                         TextColor="Blue"/>
```

Comment: As stated above with jason "Member not found in data context ''Products' error ". There is something going wrong in the itemssource

Comment: Should my Observablecollection<Products> or Observablecollection<Product>

Comment: `[0:] Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[xxx_xxxxx.Models.Category]'  `   This means that you are trying to get an IEnumerable but the response had a single value. So please try to make sure it's a list of data in your response.

Comment: In addition, why are you putting a singel mode into a single mode , that's weird.    public 
 `class Products
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: If the problem persist,  is it convinient for you to post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Can I PM u somewhere or email it to u?

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver? We are only allowed to get code in these ways.

Comment: https://newuniversity-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/sang_nguyen_student_nhlstenden_com/EeXXWGkHZa5ClfPtXIZVx8ABGodCZtLCnORJNqF55p0n2Q?e=QeYnHc New link if ur still up to help

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't open this link. You can post a basic demo to github or onedriver.